# faster way to do spline interpolation in python

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to interpolate 30 points with a degree 3 spline like so:

```
from sympy import interpolating_spline
domain_points = [0.01, 0.01888888888888889, 0.027777777777777776, 0.03666666666666667, 0.04555555555555556, 0.05444444444444445, 0.06333333333333332, 0.07222222222222222, 0.0811111111111111, 0.09, 0.09888888888888889, 0.10777777777777778, 0.11666666666666665, 0.12555555555555556, 0.13444444444444445, 0.14333333333333334, 0.15222222222222223, 0.16111111111111112, 0.17, 0.30833333333333335, 0.44666666666666666, 0.5850000000000001, 0.7233333333333334, 0.8616666666666667, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 5.5, 7.0, 8.5]
range_points = list(map(lambda x: x-1/x, domain_points))

interpolating_spline(3, x, domain_points, range_points)
```

This takes approximately ~1min 42s on my machine. Am I doing something wrong making this so slow? Is there a way to speed this up or an alternative library for spline interpolation that is faster so I could interpolate a lot more points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want numeric interpolation use scipy

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation

Sympy is for algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Use [scipy.interpolate.splrep()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html#scipy.interpolate.splprep). Its default is `k=3` but its supports upto `k=5`.

**EDIT** in response to the comment below you could also use [interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html) which actually gives you the same result. Code & graph updated to show this..

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

domain_points = [0.01, 0.01888888888888889, 0.027777777777777776, 0.03666666666666667, 0.04555555555555556, 0.05444444444444445, 0.06333333333333332, 0.07222222222222222, 0.0811111111111111, 0.09, 0.09888888888888889, 0.10777777777777778, 0.11666666666666665, 0.12555555555555556, 0.13444444444444445, 0.14333333333333334, 0.15222222222222223, 0.16111111111111112, 0.17, 0.30833333333333335, 0.44666666666666666, 0.5850000000000001, 0.7233333333333334, 0.8616666666666667, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 5.5, 7.0, 8.5]
range_points  = list(map(lambda x: x-1/x, domain_points))

# using splrep
tck           = interpolate.splrep(domain_points, range_points, s=0)
splrep_points = interpolate.splev(domain_points, tck)

tock = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(domain_points, range_points)
xs   = np.linspace(np.min(domain_points), np.max(domain_points), 1000)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(domain_points, range_points, 'x', domain_points, splrep_points, 'b', xs, tock(xs), 'r')
plt.legend(['Data', 'splrep', 'InterpolatedUnivariateSpline'])
plt.show()
```

Which gives...

[image]

Comment: Thats odd.  After the first answer I used `scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline`. Is there an advantage to use `splrep` in this case?

Comment: @user2640045 I have re-edited my reply as I thought something fishy was going on as the two fucntions should really give the same result as they are both wrappers for the same FITPACK implementation. Have fixed the use of `splrep` in the answer.